# Problems with subselect

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, aggregate

Using PostgreSQL 9.4; database: darwincore2.

I want to retrieve these fields:

```
species
county
dataeier
county
```

I want to get the count of all posts grouped by `county`, only showing the top 10 counties sorted by totals. I also need to select distinct on `species` so if there are 50 species with the same name, only count them as 1 species. And only count posts with `dataeier` containing the text 'nngg'.

Here is my code that fails with:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "darwincore2.species" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
> LINE 5:         SELECT species, county
> ```

```
SELECT DC2.county, count(DC2.*) AS nav_county 
FROM darwincore2 AS DC2, (
SELECT COUNT(*), county
FROM (
    SELECT species, county 
    FROM darwincore2
    WHERE darwincore2.dataeier ILIKE '%nngg%'
    GROUP BY county
    ) AS temp
  ) AS DC2DIST
WHERE 
DC2.country ILIKE '%norway%' 
    AND 
DC2.county = DC2DIST.county
GROUP BY DC2.county 
ORDER BY nav_county DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

### UPDATE

I was able to get the result with this code. It seems much more simple than I originally tried and give me the correct count.

```
SELECT county, count(DISTINCT species) as nav_county 
FROM darwincore2 
WHERE country ILIKE '%norway%' 
AND dataeier ILIKE '%nngg%' 
GROUP BY county 
ORDER BY nav_county DESC LIMIT 10
```

Gives me results:

```
Oslo        2254
Bærum       1923
Larvik      1608
Asker       1580
Arendal     1498
Porsgrunn   1405
Nesodden    1317
Bamble      1157
Skien       1123
Fredrikstad 1020
```

Comment: You have `county` twice in your desired output list. Please clarify. You want the `count of all posts grouped by county`, then how does `distinct on species` figure into this? Do you mean count per `(country, county, species)`? And you do you want a single row for each count or a separate row for every distinct `dataeier` - counting what *exactly*? I suspect you don't want `dataeier` in the result, just as filter, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, fixed typo's of `’` to `'`.

```
SELECT DC2.county, count(DC2.*) AS nav_county 
FROM darwincore2 AS DC2, (
SELECT COUNT(*), county
FROM (
    SELECT species, county 
    FROM darwincore2
    WHERE darwincore2.dataeier ILIKE '%nngg%'
    GROUP BY county
    ) AS temp
  ) AS DC2DIST
WHERE 
DC2.country ILIKE '%norway%' 
    AND 
DC2.county = DC2DIST.county
GROUP BY DC2.county 
ORDER BY nav_county DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be the bad single quote.  However, you should learn proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  I think the query you want is more like this:

```
SELECT DC2.county, SUM(DC2.cnt) AS nav_county 
FROM darwincore2 DC2 JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, county 
      FROM darwincore2
      WHERE darwincore2.dataeier ILIKE '%nngg%'
      GROUP BY county
     ) DC2DIST
     ON DC2.county = DC2DIST.county
WHERE DC2.country ILIKE '%norway%’ 
GROUP BY DC2.county 
ORDER BY nav_county DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Notes:

- You don't need a subquery to use aggregation.
- It is good practice to name columns in subqueries in the `FROM` clause.
- You probably intend `SUM()` in the outer query rather than `COUNT()`.
- Use explicit `JOIN` syntax.